# How to change file access on Unix "-rw-r--r--" to " -r------w- "

Tags: unix, git-bash

(not linux)

This is an exercise for my study, changing different file and directory accesses, need to learn how to manipulate with rights

I'm trying `chmod 400` and it gives `-r--r--r--`, but I need `-r------w-`, can't find how to change it for files and directories

Comment: Check out what happens as you change the numbers 400, 407, 700 etc The Man page for CHMOD will tell you.

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows?

Comment: Makes no difference (for these basic read-write rights) whether you are on Unix or Linux (or MacOS). chmod command. Read the manual. We are not going to do your home-work for you.

Comment: can't you work out the bits for `-r------w-`?

Comment: notice you don't even have to use numbers: `chmod u=r,g=,o=w file`

Comment: What happened when you read the documentation of `chmod`? Which parts of it did you understand and which parts didn't you understand? What did you do in order to understand the parts you didn't understand?